# T-SQL Bulk Insert with format file: Ignore row upon format mismatch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a bulk insert of a csv-file. (All Varchar Fields).

The file contains lines like the following:

```
"10449";"135";"Programming";"2";"020";" ";"0";"4";"0";"4";"20151229";"20151228"
```

and ends with a specific row to be able to check if we imported all data:

```
"DONE";"29/12/15";"12:15:03"
```

I have generated a non-XML format file with `bcp` which looks like this:

```
10.0
12
1       SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      1     Budgetnr                               Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      2     CustID                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       100     ";"      3     Subject                                Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      4     BNR2                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      5     BNR3                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      6     Type                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      7     BudgetX                                Latin1_General_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      8     BudgetY                                Latin1_General_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      9     TimeSpentX                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      10    TimeSpentY                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR             0       50      ";"      11    DateStrX                               Latin1_General_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\r\n"   12    DateStrY                               Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Upon using the bulk insert `with (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\formatFile2.fmt', firstrow = 3, rows_per_batch = 5000 )`

I receive the following error:

> Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

I understand this is coming from the fact that the bulk insert expects more columns but can't find any.

How do I tell MsSQL to ignore any lines that do not match the format?
(I have looked into other options like `OPENROWSET` to count the rows before importing but I'm not allowed to change the security settings at my companies server, and besides, that's just an ugly solution for doing something as simple as this).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of rows in a file, you can use `with (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\formatFile2.fmt', firstrow = 3, BATCHSIZE = number_of_rows-3 )`. Otherwise, using `BATCHSIZE = 1` will help to avoid your error, but every row will be inserted in a separate transaction. It will ruin the advantage of BULK INSERT.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but sadly, the number of lines will change weekly so I'm afraid this isn't an option :(